# Pb with ip redirection in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirection

When updating my magento shop, I would like to redirect all IP except mine to maintenance page.

I used to do that with .htaccess file :

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^5.6.7.8
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.fr [R=302,L]
```

It was working well, but I now have some problems. Sometimes it works, sometime not, and I have to disable redirection to access my site. Sometimes I can access the frontend but not the backend...

Any idea?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily redirect to the maintenence page with the following code.

This is a promising code, which we are achieving using mod_rewrite module.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 #allowed ips start
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
 #allowed ips end
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.